# Функторы и области видимости

Tags: c++11, c++

У меня в приложении есть очередь, в которой я храню функторы. Каждый этот функтор должен вернуть объект запроса Request. Этот объект формируется на основе данных локального хранилища, которое постоянно изменяется в процессе работы. Нужный функтор возвращается специальной функцией. В этой функции есть переменная `type` доступ к которой нужен внутри функтора.

```
namespace QJS {
namespace Router {
    typedef std::tr1::function<Request (Storage)> Template;

    Template get(const Router::Type &type) {
        switch (type) {
        case Router::VERSION:
            return [&](const Storage & ) -> Request {
                return Request(QUrl("http://localhost/"), type, QByteArray(), QJS::GET, true);
            };
            break;
    default:
            throw std::exception("Undefined request type", 10);
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Пока всё хорошо, а в чём вопрос-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто смените модификатор доступа лямбды к `scope` с "`[ & ]`" на "`[ = ]`", тогда **копия** `type` попадет в функтор, а не адрес локальной переменной, доступ к которой, по всей видимости, генерирует у Вас исключение.